# What does \. mean in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For example in SwiftUI we can choose dark or light mode using `environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)`, or get Identifiable key using `\.id`.

But what does this syntax mean: `\.something`

Comment: That's a key path. Please read the Swift programming language guide. It's not optional.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding it in the Language Guide, even knowing exactly what I'm looking for. The only place I see it is in deep in the Reference section (i.e. the formal grammar), which IMO beginners should not need to read before diving in. This may be a docs bug.

Comment: It's a good question for beginners!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Key-Path Expression](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html) in the Expressions section of the Language Reference in The Swift Programming Language.